# As an OAuth Server, how should I be generating and storing OAuth 2.0 Tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, security

OAuth 2 tokens are just random blobs. I've seen implementations of OAuth servers that seem to suggest storing this random string directly in the database and looking it up.

This goes against my better judgment.

A token is essentially another password for a user.  Storing these tokens in plain-text in a database - even though these passwords are generated randomly - seems like a **Bad Idea**. This is because if the database is compromised, then all the attacker would have to do is pass `auth_token=code` and impersonate any user that has a valid token.

What are the best ways of generating and storing an authorization token for OAuth 2?

Answer (score 1):

like the idea of having an opaque token that is easily revocable. But I'd like to keep an O(1) lookup time.

Assuming a key lookups are O(1) i think the following scheme should work.

```
 Client Auth Code Issued = Url64(ENC(random_index||secretkey) || HMAC)
 Database Record         = {KEY: random_index , VALUE: scrypt(secretkey)}
```

**Explanation:**

**Issuance**

1. Generate 2 random strings, a `random_index` and `secret_key`
2. Hash the `secret_key` using password hashing best-practices and store it under the `random_index` in the db.
3. Encrypt the `random_index` and `secret_key` and supply it to the client as an `auth_code`

**Validation**

1. Decrypt the client `auth_code` into `random_index` and `secret_key` components
2. Look up the token by `random_index` in the database
3. Verify the `secret_key` using the hash method during issuance.

I think the above solves the problem, but I'd welcome any other solutions.

**Note**: I would store other meta-data along with the secret key (expiration, permissions, etc..) but this unimportant to answering the question.

**Note 2**: I may also get away with using SHA2 or another fast hashing algorithm instead of `scrypt` or `bcrypt` since I control the entropy in `secret_key`.

Comment: This looks feasible. However, you may be able to get rid of `random_index` and look up tokens by other means (e.g. storing metadata such as `client_id` and `user_id` along with the token and using those for lookup).